# Can I do type-narrowing in an Angular template?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that takes a business object as an Input.  In the template for this component, I want to conditionally render some content by checking the value of a property that only exists on some subclasses of the business object.

```
export class Thing { public foo: string; }
export class SubThing extends Thing { public bar: number; }

// ...
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() thing: Thing;
}
```

---

```
<!-- template file -->
{{ thing.foo }}
<div *ngIf="thing?.bar > 10">Conditional content...</div>
```

This used to work as written because the compiler wasn't very strict about type checking in the templates.  Recently this started breaking with the AOT compiler (not sure exactly when) because, strictly speaking, `thing?.bar` is not valid when the compiler thinks `thing` is just a `Thing`, and can't say for certain that it's a `SubThing`.

I would like to say something like `*ngIf="thing instanceof SubThing && thing?.bar > 10"` but I can't use `instanceof` in the template itself.  Is there some other way I can check the type of `thing` from the template, such that the compiler stops complaining?  (I got the build working again by specifying my Input as `any` but of course I'd like to get my type checking back if possible.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently the compiler respects [User Defined Type Guards](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/typeguard#user-defined-type-guards).  I just have to define a method in my component:

```
export class MyComponent {
  // ...
  /** @internal */ isSubThing(t: Thing): t is SubThing {
    return t instanceof SubThing;
  }
}
```

---

```
<!-- template file -->
{{ thing.foo }}
<div *ngIf="isSubThing(thing) && thing?.bar > 10">
  Conditional content...
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore as of Angular 10.0.7

Comment: I use this in Angular 9 without any problems, what compiler flags do you have enabled?  Maybe you're getting caught out by strict template checking?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: As of Angular 11 it looks like type guards in templates are working correctly. My answer below might still be useful for people running earlier versions of Ivy.

There is a way in Angular Ivy to allow type narrowing in a template with strict template checking. It's a little hacky but it works. You create a method in your component to return the object if it passes the type check and undefined if it doesn't. You then use then assign the result of that method to a new variable in the ngIf expression. The new variable will be of the correct type

```
export class MyComponent {
   // ...
   
   public isSubThing(t: Thing): SubThing | undefined{
       return t instanceof SubThing? t : undefined;
   }
}
```

---

```
<!-- template file -->
{{ thing.foo }}
<ng-container *ngIf="isSubThing(thing) as subThing">
    <div *ngIf="subThing.bar > 10">
      Conditional content...
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

Here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gmqkzj

Comment: I recently switched to `strictTemplates: true` and haven't really needed to do this.  At least as of version `11.1.2`, with that flag on, your code could be written without the new variable assignment.

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For some more advanced cases this article about type guards for structural directives may be useful.

https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#directive-type-checks

```
  // Make sure the template checker knows the type of the context with which the
  // template of this directive will be rendered
  static ngTemplateContextGuard(
    directive: TrigonometryDirective,
    context: unknown
  ): context is TrigonometryContext {
    return true;
  }
```