# How to show object with Property does not exist on type in template

Tags: angular, typescript

I have object with type `WithBalance | WithoutBalance`

```
withBalance : { balance:number, name:string } withoutBalance : { name : string}


<span>{{object?.balance ?? 0}} </span>
```

But when I try to do so I get error `Property 'balance' does not exist on type WithoutBalance`.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using Type Narrowing in the angular template. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220910/can-i-do-type-narrowing-in-an-angular-template/47221093)

In such cases either introduce a new property named type in the objects with the name of the type as a string and add a condition or either check for the property inside the object in the template like the above answer.

***Solution 1***

```
withBalance : { balance:number, name:string, type:"withBalance" } withoutBalance : { name : string, type:"withoutBalance"}


<span>{{object.type=="withBalance"? object.balance: 0}} </span>
```

***Solution 2***

```
getBalance (obj:any){
    if ("balance" in obj) {
      return obj.balance
    }
    return 0;
  }

<span>
  {{ getBalance(object)}}
</span>
```

Comment: thank you for clear answer, i think solution 2  is better

Comment: but i tried to do something like this 
`getProductBalance(service: WithBalance| WithoutBalance): number 
{    
const product = service as WithBalance;
return product.balance ? product.balance : 0;
  }`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi you right, but i like this answer because it gives 2 options how to solve problem, no offense

Answer (score 1):

Optional chaining (`?.`) lets us write code where TypeScript can immediately stop running some expressions if we run into a null or undefined. So in your case you have used `object?.balance` which means if `object` is not null try to access the `balance` property. So if object is in `withoutBalance` type it raises an error like this: `Property 'balance' does not exist on type WithoutBalance`.

You can use `in` operator in your component like this:

```
getBalance (){
    if ("balance" in this.object) {
      return this.object.balance
    }
    return 0;
  }

<span>
  {{ getBalance()}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
// in your data.model.ts define the type
export interface Balance {
  name: string;
  balance?: number
}

// this is where you are going to instantiate the model
const withBalance: Balance = {
  name: 'with balance',
  balance: 50
}

const balanceExample: Balance = {
  name: 'Without balance',
  // balance is optional here so you can either add it or leave it
}

// in your template
<span> {{balanceExample.balance == null ? balanceExample.balance : 0}} </span>
```

It is important to use == null instead of withoutBalance.balance??0 because balance is of type number and if you do actually have a balance and its value happens to be 0 or 1 typescript will convert it into a boolean so using == null will ensure that it will only be true if balance is null or undefined.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround:

```
<span>{{$any(object).balance ?? 0}} </span>
```

This will silent the error. Use it if you are sure that your model is right