# How to display array of data consisting of 2 types of objects in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

When I send a request to remote server, I receive json array in return. But this array can be consisted from two different types of json object:

```
[
  {
    "country": "USA",
    "caseCount": 561,
    "caseDates": [],
  },
  {
    "country": "Canada",
    "errorDescription": "Error"
  }
]
```

I have declared two interfaces for this types and variable which value can be either of these types:

```
export interface CountryData {
  country: string;
  caseCount: number;
  caseDates: any[];
}

export interface ErrorData {
  country: string;
  errorDescription: string;
}

countryData!: Observable<(CountryData| ErrorData)[]>;
```

However, when I try to render this data on my template using `*ngFor="let data of countryData | async"`, it only allows me to render values which present in both of this interfaces, i.e. only `country` field. I want to change this behaviour, and render values, which belongs to `data` object, based on its type.

Comment: That's correct behaviour, isn't it? If you don't know whether a given value is one or the other, it's only safe to access properties both have.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but I want to find a workaround or confirm that this is futile idea.

Comment: It's unclear what outcome you're expecting. Either you need to use only the shared props or narrow the type, e.g. by filtering out one type or the other or conditionally rendering a different thing depending on which you have.

Comment: Type narrowing would be nice, but I don't know how to do this, hence the question.

Comment: Have a look at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47220910/3001761

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. This particular example is not exactly helpful, but the very concept of user defined type guard is. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a technique called [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html).

For example,

```js
interface CountryData {
  country: string;
  caseCount: number;
  caseDates: any[];
}

interface ErrorData {
  country: string;
  errorDescription: string;
}

countryDataToString(data: CountryData | ErrorData) {
  if (!data) {
    // null or undefined
    return typeof data;
  } else if ('errorDescription' in o) {
    // ErrorData
    return `ERROR for ${o.country}: ${o.errorDescription}`;
  } else {
    // CountryData
    return `${o.country} (${o.caseCount} ${o.caseCount === 1 ? 'case' : 'cases'})`;
  }
}
```