Using union types & type guards in template when using ngForOf in Angular
If I do array: (A | B)[] in an *ngFor seems like the option is to use $any() all over the template.
Is there a way to do this properly?
I avoided typing altogether with $any() but it feels bad. All other posts I've seen regarding type unions in the template were specific implementations and felt generally hacky.

Are you looking for type narrowing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47220910/can-i-do-type-narrowing-in-an-angular-template

@GetOffMyLawn I think the OP is looking for interface type narrowing, which is trickier than when A and B would be classes

Type narrowing can be on anything, it doesn't have to be just a class. test(a): a is MyIterface { return 'x' in a; }, or test(a): a is number { return typeof a === 'number'; }

If you're using interfaces, you may try and do it like this (demo). But sadly it seems you would have to create a pipe for each of your types :-/ If you're using classes, it's a multitude easier to accomplish: code - Demo - But you cannot deserialize from json then

Write a method that defines the type, which will be used in the ngFor!
get arrayA(): A {
    return this.array as A;
}

get arrayB(): B {
    return this.array as B;
}


I imagine you can define
export type typeAB=A & B
arrayAB=this.array as typeAB

And loop over arrayAB
<div *ngFor="let element of arrayAB">{{element}}</div> 

e.g. using a button
  toogleChange()
  {
    if (this.arrayAB==this.array2 as typeAB[])
       this.arrayAB=this.array as typeAB[]
    else
       this.arrayAB=this.array2 as typeAB[]
  }

